# setFocus is not a function Ionic 7 searchbar

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, vuejs3

I'm using Vue 3 and Ionic 7 and want to set the focus to a searchbar as soon as it is loaded. According to the [ionic docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/searchbar#setfocus) just use setFocus, because it sets focus on the native `input` in `ion-searchbar`. I use `onIonViewDidEnter()` to `setFocus` when it's loaded.

Then I use a [ref](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html) to access the `ion-searchbar` element (keep in mind I can't set a `ref` to the `<ion-input>`, because the element is only accessible after page load). When running:

```
onIonViewDidEnter(() => {
  searchbarRef.value.setFocus()
});
```

I get the error: TypeError: searchbarRef.value.setFocus is not a function. `searchbarRef.value` gives me back the `<ion-searchbar>`.

Now it is possible to `focus()` when targeting the child element which is the `<ion-input>`, but then I'll need to access the DOM using javascript and that's what you'll want to avoid when using Vue.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no you can't `setFocus()`, but it doesn't mean that there are no other ways to set focus to the element. For example:

```
<ion-searchbar></ion-searchbar>

<script setup lang="ts">
import {
  IonSearchbar,
  onIonViewDidEnter
} from '@ionic/vue';

onIonViewDidEnter(() => {
  const input = document.querySelector('.searchbar-input') as HTMLInputElement
  input.focus()
})
</script>
```

While I certainly do not recommend this since you'll always want to avoid using document in vue because you can use refs to access the dom.

For more information checkout [this](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/17745) thread at github.